# Adding left navigation to the sharepoint wiki page

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to remove the current navigation and instead of that i need to add some links related to the current page only.

I have removed the current navigation using css,

```
<style>
#contentRow > table > tbody > tr > td.ms-dialogHidden {
display: none;
}
</style>
```

now what should I do to get the left navigation with some links.

Comment: Firstly, I am not sure if I undestood you well, but upper navigation is called global navigation and left navigation is current navigation. What do you mean by Get the left navigation? You want to hide that one too? or you want to show some link related to your current page on the current (left) navigation?

Comment: Is this for a single page or for every page to have unique information displayed? Are you using 2010 or 2013?

Comment: I need few links for only current page that's why i am hiding the current navigation and now i want it for current page only..it is for sharepoint 2013

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to create a list of custom links for a wiki page to duplicate the left navigation. I'd create a layout page that provides a left bar with a web part zone. From there I'd add either a CQWP, CSWP, or a CEWP to solve.